# Throttled project blocked after updating Jenkins to 2.222.1

Tags: jenkins

I am using the stable jenkins release and a few days ago I `apt dist-upgrade`'d my build Jenkins server, and was updated from 2.204.4 to 2.222.1, and now I am running into issues.

The major issue is that my throttled builds do not work. I have a build that is configured with throttling, which is now stuck in the build queue forever, even if all executors are free. The pop-up says that is waiting for the next available executor, which is "master", which is the only one satisfying this label. It is idle, but Jenkins is still waiting.

The configuration worked fine before upgrading. Restarting Jenkins does not help. I have also tried dropping one of the throttling categories to see if it that was blocking the build, but to no avail.

This is a screenshot from the build server. Configuration excerpts below.

[image: Build stuck in Build Queue - Waiting for next available executor on 'master', while 'master' is completely idle]

This is the throttling configuration for the builds:

```
<hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty plugin="throttle-concurrents@2.0.2">
  <maxConcurrentPerNode>1</maxConcurrentPerNode>
  <maxConcurrentTotal>1</maxConcurrentTotal>
  <categories class="java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList">
    <string>vm-installer</string>
    <string>kickstart-repo</string>
  </categories>
  <throttleEnabled>true</throttleEnabled>
  <throttleOption>category</throttleOption>
  <limitOneJobWithMatchingParams>true</limitOneJobWithMatchingParams>
  <matrixOptions>
    <throttleMatrixBuilds>false</throttleMatrixBuilds>
    <throttleMatrixConfigurations>true</throttleMatrixConfigurations>
  </matrixOptions>
  <paramsToUseForLimit></paramsToUseForLimit>
  <configVersion>1</configVersion>
</hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty>
```

It is set up to build on a single node:

```
<hudson.matrix.LabelAxis>
  <name>label</name>
  <values>
    <string>kickstartbuild</string>
  </values>
</hudson.matrix.LabelAxis>
```

EDIT: This seems to be a bug, following up through the Jenkins bug tracker at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61779